# разные значения при каждой итерации

Tags: python

Привет всем,
Как я могу при каждой, например 10 итерации вставить значение в словарь которое я ему задам?
Например JSON:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": “A green door”,
"price": 12,
"tags": 
}
```

Моя задача что каждую 10 итерацию в tags будет пустая строка:

```
 for i in xrange(100)
     a['id'] = random.randint(100, 2000000)
     a['name'] = faker.name()
     a['price'] = random.randit(10, 20)
     a['tags'] = random.choice(['te', 'rara','tete', " "])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет, 
попробуй так:

```
a['tags'] = random.choice(['te', 'rara','tete']) if i % 10 != 0 else " "
```

Comment: Помогло спаисбо!

Comment: @max всегда пожалуйста)

Answer (score 0):

```
a['tags'] = (i%10)? random.choice(['te', 'rara','tete']) : " "
```